# How to reference bean property values?

Tags: java, spring

Here's what I am trying to do. I have a spring batch job which triggers a bean with multiple properties. I want these properties to be divided into separate beans for organizational purposes.

So I currently have this:

```
<bean id="runSQL" class="Tasklet"
    scope="step">
    <property name="sourceSQL"
        value="SQL STATEMENT HERE" />
    <property name="targetSQL"
        value="SQL STATEMENT HERE"></property>

  <property name="filePath" value="#{jobParameters['OUTPUT.FILE.PATH']}"> </property>
</bean>
```

but I basically want this (not working due to lack of class definition and I don't know if #{souce.sourceSQL} is a valid way of grabbing bean properties):

```
<bean id="runSQL" class="Tasklet"
    scope="step">
    <property name="sourceSQL"
        value="#{source.sourceSQL}" />
    <property name="targetSQL"
        value="#{target.targetSQL}"></property>

  <property name="filePath" value="#{jobParameters['OUTPUT.FILE.PATH']}">     </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sourceSQL" class="Class not needed"
    scope="step">
    <property name="sourceSQL"
        value="SQL STATEMENT HERE" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="targetSQL" class="Class not needed"
    scope="step">
    <property name="sourceSQL"
        value="SQL STATEMENT HERE" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have tried to reference the beans traditionally with

```
<ref bean="someBean"/>
```

but my Tasklet isn't designed to receive a bean, just the property values and I would prefer to leave the Tasklet as is. How do I get around this or alternative ways of storing this data for the beans?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with `#{...}`. If you want to reference a bean, stick a `@` in front of the Spring bean ID, for example `#{@sourceSQL.sourceSQL}` and `#{@targetSQL.sourceSQL}`.

See the documentation for the [Spring Expression language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef).

Comment: I'm getting the following error: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 11): Property or field 'sourceSQL' cannot be found on object of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60' - maybe not public?

Comment: Does the referenced bean actually have that property?

Comment: Yes it does. Pretty much just like the example code.